# count the total number of column field appeared more than once in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count

I am trying to run the query to get the total number of repetitions (appeared more than once) for one column called "abc" . I am trying this but not able to achieve.

```
select COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT card_no, COUNT(*)  AS cnt )
```

please help, thanks in advance.

For Example below is the column :

```
cards
123,
456
,123
```

**Result:**

```
Count
1
```

As 123 appeared more than once.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server. And it is not clear from your question or the code snippet what this is trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am using sql server.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Both as well formatted text.)

Comment: If the data were `123, 123, 456, 123` what would the result be.  1?  Or 2?

Comment: @GordonLinoff 1 will be the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the number of distinct values in the column that are repeated at least once, is that right?

```
SELECT COUNT(dupes)
FROM (SELECT card_no AS dupes, COUNT(*) cnt FROM table_name
  GROUP BY card_no HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) A
```

---

Edit for explanation.

The inner query `SELECT card_no AS dupes, COUNT(*) cnt FROM table_name GROUP BY card_no HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` returns only those values that are repeated in your table. The aliases on the columns are necessary because it's a subquery. You can run this query independently of the outer query to see what results it returns.

You have to have the group by on any field that you don't want to aggregate when you're aggregating other fields (e.g. performing a count of records), and the `HAVING` part is to filter out anything that isn't duplicated (i.e. has a count of 1). `HAVING` is the way to apply filtering on aggregated fields that you can't have in a `WHERE`.

The outer query `SELECT COUNT(dupes)...` is merely counting the number of card_no values returned by the inner query. Since these are grouped, it gives the number of distinct values that are duplicated.

`A` at the end there sets up an alias for the subquery so that it can be referenced like it's an actual table elsewhere in the query. This is necessary for any subquery in the `FROM` clause of another query. Effectively the select in the outer query reads `SELECT COUNT(A.dupes)...` and without the alias `A` there would be no way to qualify where the dupes field is being referenced from (even though in this case it's implied).

It's also worth noting that the field `COUNT(*) cnt` isn't required in the `SELECT` part of the subquery as it isn't being used anywhere else in the query. It will work just as effectively without it, as long as you still have the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses.

Comment: this is correct, can you please explain a bit the query ?

Comment: Edited for explanation. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
card_no, COUNT(*) AS "Occurrences"
FROM
YourTable
GROUP BY card_no
HAVING 
COUNT(*) > 1
```